# Export transparent material in GLTF in blender 2.8

Tags: transparency, glass, gltf

I am trying to export a glass material in gltf. Here is the material principled shader, notice I have **transmission** set to 1.0:

[image: principled shader]

this gives me this result in cycles (the glasses have the glass material):

[image: van with glass]

However when I export this to gltf, and view it in the [gltf viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) or load it in my webgl application, this is the result:

[image: webgl van]

How do I export glass?

I already have this in my render options:

[image: render transparency]

I am using blender 2.8 beta, all the other questions I could find all refer to an older version of blender.

EDIT: I don't even have the Blend Mode dropdown in my shader settings:

[image: shader settings]

Comment: A big comprehensive write up in blender docs would be good for this challenging transition where V8 and Blender are tops

Answer (score 9):

#### Transmission (of light, such as glass and water)

**UPDATE**: Blender 2.91 and above support [exporting transmission directly](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#transmission) as shown in the original post above, using glTF's [`KHR_materials_transmission`](https://www.khronos.org/news/press/khronos-releases-wave-of-new-gltf-pbr-3d-material-capabilities) extension.  Not all renderers support this.  ThreeJS, PlayCanvas, Adobe Dimension, Microsoft's BabylonJS, and Google Filament are among the rendering engines known to support transmission in glTF.

#### Alpha Blending

glTF 2.0 has always had an alpha blending mode available, but it's intent is just to be "coverage" (like medical gauze tape), not a physically correct optical translucency (as the latter was considered too high a target for the initial release of 2.0).  Basically this means that low alpha values will dissolve the entire material, including specular reflections.  Even so, the mode is often used to emulate clear materials like glass, particularly for situations where real transmission support is not available.

To control the blend mode, look for a settings panel near the bottom of the material properties set of panels.  Blender offers many choices here.  glTF supports three of them: Opaque, Alpha Blend, and Alpha Clip (along with the "Clip Threshold" value in that case).

> NOTE: Eevee must be the selected rendering engine, to reveal this blend mode setting.  The user's selection will be remembered and used by the glTF exporter even when other engines such as Cycles are selected.

The alpha values come from the "Alpha" input on the Principled BSDF node, and when exporting to glTF, they are stored in the alpha channel of the base color texture.

[image: Blend Mode]

Comment: Thanks for the insight! However I am not finding the Blend Mode setting, I even downloaded the latest beta right now, do I need to do something specific? https://i.imgur.com/dzoTVVa.png

Comment: Hmm, it's there when Eevee is selected as the rendering engine (in the Scene tab), but when I switch to Cycles, these options disappear.  This might need to be filed as an exporter issue, not accounting for blend modes in Cycles.  I guess the workaround would be to temporarily switch to Eevee to edit the material settings.

Comment: Ok, I've been able to make the material transparent also, in eevee, following this guide, however the gltf export still exports an opaque material. Should I report this bug to the blender issue tracker?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81851/does-transparency-work-in-eevee

Comment: When you switched to Eevee, did you find the "blend mode" -> "alpha blend" setting on the material, similar to the screenshot above?  This, plus an alpha channel in the base color texture, should cause the current exporter to ask for blending in glTF.  If you still need to file an issue, the tracker is here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues