# Cannot Export as GLTF file with volumetric mesh in Blender 2.83

Tags: export, volumetrics, gltf, webgl

I am trying to export a personal project I made in GLTF format. The problem I am getting is the volumetric mesh looks black when exported. Is there any way how to overcome this problem[[image: the image with black cube has Principled Volume applied]][1[image: ]]

Comment: Maybe you need to [enable alpha blending](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129817/18161)?

Comment: @emackey i tried alpha blending but its still not working..the mesh has Principled Volume applied to it....

Comment: Yeah, you can't store arbitrary Blender nodes in glTF.  glTF has a specific PBR material definition, and the glTF exporter looks for certain fields on specific nodes that can be converted to that form.  There is [documentation on this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#materials).