# how to solve dark edges image area when using transparency in eevee

Tags: light, transparency

SOLUTION that worked for this project: edge fading to 0 AND mark overscan

[image]I am trying to adapt an image i made in cycles to eevee.
this has a (up & down moving) flat, transparent layer slightly beyond the full width of the camera view with a white background.

I have used settings as set out here:
[Does transparency work in eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81851/does-transparency-work-in-eevee)

however, when I render in eevee the transparent material is getting darker near the camera borders. (not the white background)

I've tried making the transparent layer wider, and did some changes in lighting, unchecked passepartout in camera(although that stated outside the image area). but that did not resolve it. Turning the sun off did make a change.

This is not what i want, so is it possible to turn that feature off?

i've made an example file(is the picture above):

[image]

Comment: The fact is that pbr has a nice and cheap effect but is quite uncontrolable, for picture renders i suggest you keep working with cycles.

Comment: that is ashame, because i wanted to explore this for an animation.

Comment: Oh. In this case you should nevertheless post your blend file. Someone might look into it and find a solution.

Comment: You've updated with a blend. Post the image so that people can offer you help without needing the actual file.

Comment: sorry, is this better?

Comment: Are you using screen space effects? There is an option somewhere I think to render slightly outside the camera's view to help with lack of data. Oversampling or something like that

Comment: yes, screen space effect with refraction is on.

Comment: when setting edge fading to 0 it minimizes the dark border, but does not remove it completely.

Comment: By setting edge fading to 0 AND mark overscan, the problem seems to have dissolved in the test file i made. 
I will try to create the animation with these setting to see if it has no other negative effects. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting under *Screen Space Reflections* on the *Render Settings* tab called *Edge Fading*. Just turn that to zero.