# How was Regency logo effect done?

Tags: shaders, light, effects

I'm trying to create a similar effect to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSv1lmXD1RM&list=PLJEq1MpS_fKF_4IehO1V69vii9ws5ZLDo&index=4&ab_channel=SebastianDecilia). And I found a nice tutorial with something [similar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvsSuZ7I0BY&list=PLJEq1MpS_fKF_4IehO1V69vii9ws5ZLDo&index=5&t=1450s&ab_channel=DylanNeill). However, I wasn't able to add a text there. So it looks like the [material setup](https://fotos.subefotos.com/4ad9d8c48f2c37e3c8106572355c7f38o.png) is not using any volumetrics at all? Can you help to decipher this shader?

[image]

Comment: hello could you please make a more explicite title and display at least one screenshot from the clip?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and uses link only references. Please [edit] your question so that all information is contained here for readers to see, and please specify the render engine you intend to use.

Comment: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought it was clear. Will it help if I edit the question? @moonbots gave the answer, just amazing, thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, editing the question would help. Just read the link I've posted and edit your question accordingly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get something pretty close:

[image]

I've created this mesh from the logo:

[image]

Then I've given it a pure white *Emission* shader for the bottom, and this node setup for the walls, which is basically a mix between an *Emission* of a multicolor *ColorRamp* and a *Transparent*, with a gradient along the Z axis, and before the *Output*, a *Layer Weight* to give it a pink emission on the edges:

[image]

If you want to animate, use an empty in the *Texure Coordinate* to mix the materials with a *Transparent* node:

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! And you have that minimal setup compared to the original.

Comment: Did the same setup as yours but it didn't look right. Then discovered that need to turn on Alpha Blend in the Material > Settings > Blend Mode, and check that everything basically as is here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81851/does-transparency-work-in-eevee#answer-124453

Comment: yes I didn't go into much detail, if you ever don't understand something please ask  ;)