# Transparent node makes mesh in EEVEE black but not in Cycles

Tags: rendering, materials

EDIT!!

Thanks to https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/58628/strategad
My question is resolved

[Does transparency work in eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81851/does-transparency-work-in-eevee/129787)
End of edit..

I have 1 mesh object and 2 materials assigned to it.
1 main material and 1 slot below this material.
The main material is NOT transparent and the 2nd material is.

Now when I use EEVEE the transparent material does not become transparent. When using Cycles it does.

Is it possible to get the 2nd material to be transparent in EEVEE?
I think it has to do with the fact that the main material is blocking the second one for being rendered by Blenders EEVEE?

Appriciate the help

Comment: in Eevee you need to go into Material > Settings > Blend Mode and choose Alpha Blend for example

Comment: Sorry for asking this question as it is already answered in this thread

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81851/does-transparency-work-in-eevee/129787